# Symfony routing - How can I implement a rule that redirects any URL that matches a specific pattern?

Tags: regex, url, redirect, symfony1, routes

Let's say I want any URLs that contains the word "potatoes" to be redirected to http://www.mysite.com/home

Is there any smart routing rule that can achieve that ?
Or should I use a filter ?

*PS: I'm using Symfony 1.4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this probably would be possible by writing your own `sfRoute` class, and try to override the `matchesUrl()` function. But this requires quite deep knowledge of symfony.

Probably it's more easy just to add an .htaccess rewrite rule, something like this (not tested):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)potatoes(.*)$ index.php/home [R=301]
```

This of course only works if your webserver is Apache, otherwise you have to find an equivalent for your webserver.

Comment: Hm, I like the idea of using the .htaccess file. But actually, I would need variables to be able to redirect
http://www.mysite/potatoes/whateverthereisafter to http://www.mysite/home/whateverthereisafter. Can you do that in an .htaccess ?

Comment: Ok, you can use $1 to capture what's in the parenthesis.

Comment: Ehm... you said "potatoes is anywhere in the URL"... if your URL has a structure like mysite/potatoes/{something}, you should probably use the symfony routing system. You could create a rule in your routing.yml, and then redirect to the appropriate action (url).